# colspan TD always centered inside a scrollable div?

Tags: html, css

Check out this one, http://jsfiddle.net/qsznwdkx/1/.

Is it possible to make the `Be Middle (.middle)` always centered even it scrolled to the right side in pure CSS?

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsznwdkx/2/)**

```
.middle{
    position:fixed;
    left:10%;
}
```

**EDIT:** [**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsznwdkx/10/)

```
td.middle {
    position: relative;
}
td.middle>span {
    left:40%;
    position: sticky;
}
```

Reference: **[URL](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/position/)**

Comment: Actually I have tried before, but some problem happened when the axis-y can be scrolled. Like this [http://jsfiddle.net/qsznwdkx/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/qsznwdkx/3/)

Comment: But `position:sticky` is being removed in new version browser nowaday. Anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Align "Be Middle' to the center and fix its position,

```
position:fixed;
```